# my query returns many records per id, I just one any of them per id

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi friends from Stack Overflow. I am trying to run a query in MS Access, i just want one record per ID randomly, but I am getting all.

I tried with distinct is not working, and I try with top, didn't work either.

this is my table below originaldata

```
ID  HotelName Role Email
__________________________
1  bandb  admin test1@email.com
1  bandb  admin test2@email.com
1  bandb  admin test3@email.com
1  bandb  user  myuser@email.com
2  myhtl  admin myhotel@email.com
3  ben    admin ben@test.com
3  ben    user  ben2@test.com
4  moon   admin moon@moon.com
4  moon   admin moon@moon2.com

I want to get the below results

ID  HotelName Role Email
__________________________
1  bandb  admin test1@email.com
2  myhtl  admin myhotel@email.com
3  ben    admin ben@test.com
4  moon   admin moon@moon.com


SELECT  *
FROM OriginalData
WHERE (((OriginalData.[Role])='admin') AND ((OriginalData.[ID]) In (Select Distinct [ID] from [OriginalData] where [Role] = 'Admin'  )));
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Is there any column able to represent the order? How did you decide which email you want to get.

Comment: @d-Shih at this point is remdonly any admin will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would be OK with displaying the "minimum" email address per each hotel group, then the following query should work:

```
SELECT od1.ID, od1.HotelName, od1.Role, od1.Email
FROM OriginalData od1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, Hotel, MIN(Email) AS min_email
    FROM OriginalData
    WHERE Role = 'admin'
    GROUP BY ID, Hotel
) od2
    ON od1.ID = od2.ID AND
       od1.Hotel = od2.Hotel AND
       od1.Email = od2.min_email
WHERE
    od1.Role = 'admin'
ORDER BY
    od1.ID;
```

**Edit:**

Coincidentally, for the exact data you showed us, you might also be able to simplify to:

```
SELECT ID, Hotel, Role, MIN(Email) AS Email
FROM OriginalData
WHERE Role = 'admin'
GROUP BY ID, Hotel, Role;
```

However, this only works because all the columns you want to appear are either aggregates or constants.  If you had other columns specific to a matching minimum row, this would not work.

Comment: Thank you for this. it works. just what I wanted. the only thing that access gives me two prompts 1 says "Enter Parameter Quey1.Expr1000"  and "enter parameter  Query1.SKUGroupID". I just left it blank and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, min(HOTELNAME), min(ROLE), min(EMAIL)
from OriginalData
group by ID
```

Comment: Actually this works. the only part missing was where role="admin". Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well this is easy but with a twist  (notice the the TOP 1...it will return just one record

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM OriginalData
WHERE OriginalData.[Role])='admin'
```

The problem is that in order to get Random you need to use something for randomize it for some value ...here lets take ID
So the SQL will be :

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM OriginalData
    WHERE OriginalData.[Role])='admin' AND ID = Clng(Rnd() * Dmax("ID","OriginalData")
```

Comment: Hi this only gives me one record from my 214k records, I need one record per id which means I need around 5k records. Thank you anyways